# Smooth the stair-like surface plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, interpolation

how can I smooth / extrapolate surface plot to avoid stair-like jumps in the envelope?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None, delimiter=";",
                 na_values=[None], names=["X", "Y", "Z"])


df['Z'] = df['Z'].astype(float)
X = df["X"].unique()
Y = df["Y"].unique()

XX, YY = np.meshgrid(X, Y)
ZZ = df["Z"].to_numpy().reshape(Y.size, X.size)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.contourf(XX, YY, ZZ, 25, cmap='jet')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here is the data:

```
0;0;0
100;0;0
200;0;0
300;0;0
400;0;0
500;0;0
600;0;0
700;0;0
800;0;0
900;0;0
1000;0;0
1100;0;0
1200;0;0
1300;0;0
1400;0;0
1500;0;0
1600;0;0
1700;0;0
1800;0;0
1900;0;0
2000;0;0
2100;0;0
2200;0;0
2300;0;0
2400;0;0
2500;0;0
2600;0;0
2700;0;0
2800;0;0
2900;0;0
3000;0;0
3100;0;0
3200;0;0
3300;0;0
3400;0;0
3500;0;0
3600;0;0
3700;0;0
3800;0;0
3900;0;0
4000;0;0
4100;0;0
4200;0;0
4300;0;0
4400;0;0
4500;0;0
4600;0;0
4700;0;0
4800;0;0
4900;0;0
5000;0;0
5100;0;0
5200;0;0
5300;0;0
5400;0;0
5500;0;0
5600;0;0
5700;0;0
5800;0;0
5900;0;0
6000;0;0
6100;0;0
6200;0;0
6300;0;0
6400;0;0
6500;0;0
6600;0;0
6700;0;0
6800;0;0
6900;0;0
7000;0;0
7100;0;0
7200;0;0
7300;0;0
7400;0;0
7500;0;0
7600;0;0
7700;0;0
7800;0;0
7900;0;0
8000;0;0
8100;0;0
8200;0;0
8300;0;0
8400;0;0
8500;0;0
8600;0;0
8700;0;0
8800;0;0
8900;0;0
9000;0;0
9100;0;0
9200;0;0
9300;0;0
9400;0;0
9500;0;0
9600;0;0
9700;0;0
9800;0;0
9900;0;0
10000;0;0
0;5;0
100;5;43.775
200;5;60.729
300;5;69.712
400;5;75.267
500;5;79.037
600;5;81.759
700;5;83.815
800;5;85.42
900;5;86.706
1000;5;87.759
1100;5;88.636
1200;5;89.376
1300;5;90.009
1400;5;90.555
1500;5;91.031
1600;5;91.448
1700;5;91.817
1800;5;92.146
1900;5;92.439
2000;5;92.702
2100;5;92.94
2200;5;93.155
2300;5;93.35
2400;5;93.528
2500;5;93.691
2600;5;93.839
2700;5;93.976
2800;5;94.102
2900;5;94.218
3000;5;94.325
3100;5;94.424
3200;5;94.516
3300;5;94.601
3400;5;94.679
3500;5;94.753
3600;5;94.821
3700;5;94.884
3800;5;94.943
3900;5;94.998
4000;5;95.05
4100;5;95.098
4200;5;95.142
4300;5;95.184
4400;5;95.223
4500;5;95.259
4600;5;95.293
4700;5;95.324
4800;5;95.354
4900;5;95.381
5000;5;95.407
5100;5;95.43
5200;5;95.452
5300;5;95.473
5400;5;95.492
5500;5;95.509
5600;5;95.526
5700;5;95.541
5800;5;95.554
5900;5;95.567
6000;5;95.579
6100;5;95.589
6200;5;95.599
6300;5;95.602
6400;5;95.573
6500;5;95.511
6600;5;95.428
6700;5;95.325
6800;5;95.208
6900;5;95.074
7000;5;94.925
7100;5;94.779
7200;5;94.619
7300;5;94.443
7400;5;94.278
7500;5;94.103
7600;5;93.929
7700;5;93.748
7800;5;93.577
7900;5;93.365
8000;5;93.212
8100;5;93.044
8200;5;92.832
8300;5;92.678
8400;5;92.511
8500;5;92.365
8600;5;92.23
8700;5;92.025
8800;5;91.908
8900;5;91.668
9000;5;91.529
9100;5;91.461
9200;5;91.308
9300;5;91.147
9400;5;90.975
9500;5;90.885
9600;5;90.695
9700;5;90.594
9800;5;90.383
9900;5;90.27
10000;5;90.221
0;10;0
100;10;28.723
200;10;44.58
300;10;54.629
400;10;61.562
500;10;66.634
600;10;70.502
700;10;73.55
800;10;76.012
900;10;78.041
1000;10;79.743
1100;10;81.189
1200;10;82.433
1300;10;83.515
1400;10;84.463
1500;10;85.301
1600;10;86.047
1700;10;86.715
1800;10;87.316
1900;10;87.859
2000;10;88.353
2100;10;88.804
2200;10;89.217
2300;10;89.597
2400;10;89.946
2500;10;90.27
2600;10;90.569
2700;10;90.848
2800;10;91.107
2900;10;91.349
3000;10;91.576
3100;10;91.788
3200;10;91.987
3300;10;92.174
3400;10;92.35
3500;10;92.516
3600;10;92.673
3700;10;92.821
3800;10;92.961
3900;10;93.094
4000;10;93.22
4100;10;93.34
4200;10;93.454
4300;10;93.562
4400;10;93.665
4500;10;93.763
4600;10;93.857
4700;10;93.946
4800;10;94.032
4900;10;94.113
5000;10;94.191
5100;10;94.266
5200;10;94.338
5300;10;94.406
5400;10;94.472
5500;10;94.535
5600;10;94.595
5700;10;94.653
5800;10;94.709
5900;10;94.755
6000;10;94.774
6100;10;94.767
6200;10;94.735
6300;10;94.69
6400;10;94.636
6500;10;94.562
6600;10;94.475
6700;10;94.377
6800;10;94.297
6900;10;94.193
7000;10;94.084
7100;10;93.976
7200;10;93.867
7300;10;93.753
7400;10;93.641
7500;10;93.518
7600;10;93.428
7700;10;93.308
7800;10;93.198
7900;10;93.056
8000;10;92.983
8100;10;92.88
8200;10;92.768
8300;10;92.648
8400;10;92.519
8500;10;92.459
8600;10;92.313
8700;10;92.295
8800;10;92.168
8900;10;92.053
9000;10;91.968
9100;10;91.878
9200;10;91.782
9300;10;91.639
9400;10;91.64
9500;10;91.529
9600;10;91.483
9700;10;91.358
9800;10;91.303
9900;10;91.245
10000;10;91.1
0;15;0
100;15;21.556
200;15;35.446
300;15;45.139
400;15;52.286
500;15;57.772
600;15;62.115
700;15;65.639
800;15;68.554
900;15;71.005
1000;15;73.095
1100;15;74.897
1200;15;76.467
1300;15;77.848
1400;15;79.07
1500;15;80.16
1600;15;81.137
1700;15;82.019
1800;15;82.819
1900;15;83.547
2000;15;84.212
2100;15;84.823
2200;15;85.385
2300;15;85.904
2400;15;86.385
2500;15;86.831
2600;15;87.247
2700;15;87.635
2800;15;87.998
2900;15;88.338
3000;15;88.658
3100;15;88.958
3200;15;89.241
3300;15;89.508
3400;15;89.76
3500;15;89.999
3600;15;90.225
3700;15;90.44
3800;15;90.644
3900;15;90.838
4000;15;91.022
4100;15;91.198
4200;15;91.366
4300;15;91.526
4400;15;91.68
4500;15;91.826
4600;15;91.966
4700;15;92.101
4800;15;92.229
4900;15;92.353
5000;15;92.472
5100;15;92.586
5200;15;92.695
5300;15;92.801
5400;15;92.902
5500;15;92.997
5600;15;93.055
5700;15;93.075
5800;15;93.077
5900;15;93.061
6000;15;93.007
6100;15;92.952
6200;15;92.878
6300;15;92.809
6400;15;92.724
6500;15;92.641
6600;15;92.542
6700;15;92.458
6800;15;92.316
6900;15;92.252
7000;15;92.124
7100;15;92.014
7200;15;91.915
7300;15;91.781
7400;15;91.701
7500;15;91.57
7600;15;91.47
7700;15;91.355
7800;15;91.229
7900;15;91.127
8000;15;91.038
8100;15;90.884
8200;15;90.817
8300;15;90.642
8400;15;90.562
8500;15;90.475
8600;15;90.379
8700;15;90.23
8800;15;90.119
8900;15;90.001
9000;15;89.876
9100;15;89.83
9200;15;89.692
9300;15;89.545
9400;15;89.485
9500;15;89.324
9600;15;89.247
9700;15;89.053
9800;15;88.962
9900;15;88.748
10000;15;88.641
0;20;0
100;20;17.143
200;20;29.257
300;20;38.271
400;20;45.238
500;20;50.783
600;20;55.302
700;20;59.054
800;20;62.22
900;20;64.925
1000;20;67.265
1100;20;69.307
1200;20;71.106
1300;20;72.701
1400;20;74.127
1500;20;75.407
1600;20;76.564
1700;20;77.614
1800;20;78.572
1900;20;79.448
2000;20;80.253
2100;20;80.995
2200;20;81.681
2300;20;82.317
2400;20;82.908
2500;20;83.46
2600;20;83.975
2700;20;84.457
2800;20;84.909
2900;20;85.334
3000;20;85.735
3100;20;86.112
3200;20;86.469
3300;20;86.806
3400;20;87.126
3500;20;87.429
3600;20;87.717
3700;20;87.99
3800;20;88.251
3900;20;88.5
4000;20;88.737
4100;20;88.963
4200;20;89.179
4300;20;89.387
4400;20;89.585
4500;20;89.775
4600;20;89.957
4700;20;90.132
4800;20;90.3
4900;20;90.462
5000;20;90.617
5100;20;90.767
5200;20;90.906
5300;20;90.993
5400;20;91.04
5500;20;91.041
5600;20;91.013
5700;20;90.958
5800;20;90.904
5900;20;90.8
6000;20;90.7
6100;20;90.594
6200;20;90.513
6300;20;90.36
6400;20;90.236
6500;20;90.093
6600;20;89.929
6700;20;89.818
6800;20;89.661
6900;20;89.517
7000;20;89.297
7100;20;89.158
7200;20;88.937
7300;20;88.768
7400;20;88.581
7500;20;88.372
7600;20;88.198
7700;20;87.954
7800;20;87.785
7900;20;87.402
8000;20;87.261
8100;20;86.931
8200;20;86.571
8300;20;86.149
8400;20;85.651
8500;20;84.934
8600;20;NaN
8700;20;NaN
8800;20;NaN
8900;20;NaN
9000;20;NaN
9100;20;NaN
9200;20;NaN
9300;20;NaN
9400;20;NaN
9500;20;NaN
9600;20;NaN
9700;20;NaN
9800;20;NaN
9900;20;NaN
10000;20;NaN
0;25;0
100;25;14.542
200;25;24.631
300;25;32.887
400;25;39.506
500;25;44.932
600;25;49.46
700;25;53.295
800;25;56.585
900;25;59.439
1000;25;61.937
1100;25;64.142
1200;25;66.103
1300;25;67.858
1400;25;69.437
1500;25;70.866
1600;25;72.165
1700;25;73.351
1800;25;74.438
1900;25;75.438
2000;25;76.361
2100;25;77.215
2200;25;78.008
2300;25;78.746
2400;25;79.434
2500;25;80.078
2600;25;80.681
2700;25;81.247
2800;25;81.78
2900;25;82.282
3000;25;82.756
3100;25;83.204
3200;25;83.628
3300;25;84.031
3400;25;84.412
3500;25;84.775
3600;25;85.121
3700;25;85.45
3800;25;85.763
3900;25;86.063
4000;25;86.35
4100;25;86.623
4200;25;86.886
4300;25;87.137
4400;25;87.378
4500;25;87.61
4600;25;87.832
4700;25;88.046
4800;25;88.251
4900;25;88.449
5000;25;88.597
5100;25;88.662
5200;25;88.669
5300;25;88.641
5400;25;88.564
5500;25;88.454
5600;25;88.343
5700;25;88.173
5800;25;87.978
5900;25;87.779
6000;25;87.619
6100;25;87.334
6200;25;87.094
6300;25;86.786
6400;25;86.432
6500;25;86.029
6600;25;85.728
6700;25;85.226
6800;25;84.582
6900;25;83.788
7000;25;82.493
7100;25;NaN
7200;25;NaN
7300;25;NaN
7400;25;NaN
7500;25;NaN
7600;25;NaN
7700;25;NaN
7800;25;NaN
7900;25;NaN
8000;25;NaN
8100;25;NaN
8200;25;NaN
8300;25;NaN
8400;25;NaN
8500;25;NaN
8600;25;NaN
8700;25;NaN
8800;25;NaN
8900;25;NaN
9000;25;NaN
9100;25;NaN
9200;25;NaN
9300;25;NaN
9400;25;NaN
9500;25;NaN
9600;25;NaN
9700;25;NaN
9800;25;NaN
9900;25;NaN
10000;25;NaN
0;30;0
100;30;11.622
200;30;20.82
300;30;28.279
400;30;34.45
500;30;39.64
600;30;44.065
700;30;47.882
800;30;51.209
900;30;54.134
1000;30;56.725
1100;30;59.037
1200;30;61.112
1300;30;62.985
1400;30;64.684
1500;30;66.232
1600;30;67.648
1700;30;68.949
1800;30;70.147
1900;30;71.255
2000;30;72.282
2100;30;73.236
2200;30;74.126
2300;30;74.957
2400;30;75.736
2500;30;76.466
2600;30;77.152
2700;30;77.798
2800;30;78.408
2900;30;78.984
3000;30;79.529
3100;30;80.045
3200;30;80.536
3300;30;81.001
3400;30;81.444
3500;30;81.866
3600;30;82.268
3700;30;82.653
3800;30;83.019
3900;30;83.37
4000;30;83.706
4100;30;84.028
4200;30;84.337
4300;30;84.633
4400;30;84.918
4500;30;85.191
4600;30;85.454
4700;30;85.684
4800;30;85.875
4900;30;85.931
5000;30;85.873
5100;30;85.747
5200;30;85.589
5300;30;85.309
5400;30;84.994
5500;30;84.567
5600;30;84.204
5700;30;83.5
5800;30;82.652
5900;30;81.491
6000;30;NaN
6100;30;NaN
6200;30;NaN
6300;30;NaN
6400;30;NaN
6500;30;NaN
6600;30;NaN
6700;30;NaN
6800;30;NaN
6900;30;NaN
7000;30;NaN
7100;30;NaN
7200;30;NaN
7300;30;NaN
7400;30;NaN
7500;30;NaN
7600;30;NaN
7700;30;NaN
7800;30;NaN
7900;30;NaN
8000;30;NaN
8100;30;NaN
8200;30;NaN
8300;30;NaN
8400;30;NaN
8500;30;NaN
8600;30;NaN
8700;30;NaN
8800;30;NaN
8900;30;NaN
9000;30;NaN
9100;30;NaN
9200;30;NaN
9300;30;NaN
9400;30;NaN
9500;30;NaN
9600;30;NaN
9700;30;NaN
9800;30;NaN
9900;30;NaN
10000;30;NaN
0;35;0
100;35;96.527
200;35;17.603
300;35;24.265
400;35;29.928
500;35;34.8
600;35;39.036
700;35;42.754
800;35;46.042
900;35;48.971
1000;35;51.596
1100;35;53.963
1200;35;56.107
1300;35;58.059
1400;35;59.843
1500;35;61.481
1600;35;62.988
1700;35;64.381
1800;35;65.671
1900;35;66.871
2000;35;67.987
2100;35;69.03
2200;35;70.006
2300;35;70.922
2400;35;71.782
2500;35;72.592
2600;35;73.355
2700;35;74.077
2800;35;74.759
2900;35;75.406
3000;35;76.019
3100;35;76.602
3200;35;77.156
3300;35;77.684
3400;35;78.188
3500;35;78.668
3600;35;79.127
3700;35;79.566
3800;35;79.986
3900;35;80.389
4000;35;80.775
4100;35;81.146
4200;35;81.502
4300;35;81.844
4400;35;82.173
4500;35;82.49
4600;35;82.636
4700;35;82.522
4800;35;82.302
4900;35;81.917
5000;35;81.253
5100;35;80.269
5200;35;78.316
5300;35;NaN
5400;35;NaN
5500;35;NaN
5600;35;NaN
5700;35;NaN
5800;35;NaN
5900;35;NaN
6000;35;NaN
6100;35;NaN
6200;35;NaN
6300;35;NaN
6400;35;NaN
6500;35;NaN
6600;35;NaN
6700;35;NaN
6800;35;NaN
6900;35;NaN
7000;35;NaN
7100;35;NaN
7200;35;NaN
7300;35;NaN
7400;35;NaN
7500;35;NaN
7600;35;NaN
7700;35;NaN
7800;35;NaN
7900;35;NaN
8000;35;NaN
8100;35;NaN
8200;35;NaN
8300;35;NaN
8400;35;NaN
8500;35;NaN
8600;35;NaN
8700;35;NaN
8800;35;NaN
8900;35;NaN
9000;35;NaN
9100;35;NaN
9200;35;NaN
9300;35;NaN
9400;35;NaN
9500;35;NaN
9600;35;NaN
9700;35;NaN
9800;35;NaN
9900;35;NaN
10000;35;NaN
0;40;0
100;40;80.252
200;40;14.856
300;40;20.741
400;40;25.863
500;40;30.362
600;40;34.344
700;40;37.893
800;40;41.077
900;40;43.949
1000;40;46.553
1100;40;48.924
1200;40;51.092
1300;40;53.083
1400;40;54.917
1500;40;56.611
1600;40;58.182
1700;40;59.642
1800;40;61.002
1900;40;62.273
2000;40;63.462
2100;40;64.578
2200;40;65.627
2300;40;66.615
2400;40;67.546
2500;40;68.427
2600;40;69.26
2700;40;70.049
2800;40;70.798
2900;40;71.51
3000;40;72.187
3100;40;72.832
3200;40;73.447
3300;40;74.035
3400;40;74.596
3500;40;75.133
3600;40;75.647
3700;40;76.139
3800;40;76.612
3900;40;77.065
4000;40;77.501
4100;40;77.92
4200;40;78.323
4300;40;78.496
4400;40;78.403
4500;40;NaN
4600;40;NaN
4700;40;NaN
4800;40;NaN
4900;40;NaN
5000;40;NaN
5100;40;NaN
5200;40;NaN
5300;40;NaN
5400;40;NaN
5500;40;NaN
5600;40;NaN
5700;40;NaN
5800;40;NaN
5900;40;NaN
6000;40;NaN
6100;40;NaN
6200;40;NaN
6300;40;NaN
6400;40;NaN
6500;40;NaN
6600;40;NaN
6700;40;NaN
6800;40;NaN
6900;40;NaN
7000;40;NaN
7100;40;NaN
7200;40;NaN
7300;40;NaN
7400;40;NaN
7500;40;NaN
7600;40;NaN
7700;40;NaN
7800;40;NaN
7900;40;NaN
8000;40;NaN
8100;40;NaN
8200;40;NaN
8300;40;NaN
8400;40;NaN
8500;40;NaN
8600;40;NaN
8700;40;NaN
8800;40;NaN
8900;40;NaN
9000;40;NaN
9100;40;NaN
9200;40;NaN
9300;40;NaN
9400;40;NaN
9500;40;NaN
9600;40;NaN
9700;40;NaN
9800;40;NaN
9900;40;NaN
10000;40;NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `SmoothBivariateSpline` to interpolate `NAN` values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import SmoothBivariateSpline

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", header=None, delimiter=";",
                 na_values=[None], names=["X", "Y", "Z"])

df['Z'] = df['Z'].astype(float)

x = df["X"]

y = df["Y"]

z = df["Z"]

xnew = np.unique(x)
ynew = np.unique(y)

mask = ~np.isnan(z)
x=(x[mask])
y=(y[mask])
z=(z[mask])


f = SmoothBivariateSpline(x,y,z,kx=1,ky=1)

znew=np.transpose(f(xnew, ynew))


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.contourf(xnew, ynew, znew, 25, cmap='jet')
plt.show()
```

You get the figure :
[image: Interpolated]